# Get multiple values in a single cell with array formula

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I'm trying to get an array formula to get the multiple results in a single cell. Is that possible?

For example below, I'd like to show in D2 all the names in column B corresponding to rows for values less than 4 in column A.

[image]

My current attempt below:

```
A   C
2   Jane
3   John
6   Thomas
1   Michael
2   Mary
7   Jason
3   Gloria
1   Andrea


=CONCAT(INDEX($B$2:$B$9,IF($A$2:$A$9<4,$B$2:$B$9)))
```

My desired result would be:

```
Jane, Michael, Mary, Andrea
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `FILTER()` then `TEXTJOIN()`.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(B2:B9,A2:A9<4))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to do it in excel 2016, 2019 that doesn't have filter?

Comment: 2019 you can. 2019 has `TEXTJOIN()`. Try array formula `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(A2:A9<4,B2:B9,""))`. For 2016 you need custom textjoin() vba UDF.

Comment: it works, both solutions. thanks so much.